# Android Glide Image is not showing on the first screen

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Android glide to load remote images, but here i met a strange problem which image on the first screen not showing but while i scroll down and scroll up again, those images become showing normally.here is the screen shot:
[image]
I have also googled such question and find a [duplicate](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1026),and after trying such steps it still doesn't work, and you may need to check code, here is it:

```
public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
private int resourceId;
private List<Site> sites = null;
private Context context;
private SiteHolder siteHolder;
/**
 * @param context the current activity context, we can get it using the super ArrayAdapter constructor
 * @param resource the site_layout.xml file
 * @param objects the collection to store all the sites
 */
public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Site> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resource;
    this.sites = objects;
}

@Override
public Site getItem(int position) {
    return sites.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sites.size();
}

//get the viewpage which inflate by site_layout.xml file
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Site site = getItem(position);
    View view = convertView;
    siteHolder = new SiteHolder();
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(resourceId, null);
    }
    //this place we need to get the whole widget in site_layout.xml file
    siteHolder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    siteHolder.address = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    siteHolder.mallName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    siteHolder.distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    siteHolder.address.setText(site.getAddress());
    //set name of the view
    siteHolder.mallName.setText(site.getName());
    //set price of the view
    //set distance of the view
    siteHolder.distance.setText("<" + site.getDistance() + "m");
    //set image
    ImageTask task = new ImageTask();
    task.execute("http://xxxx/springmvc/getFirst/" + site.getName());
    return view;
}

//检测adapater中加载网络资源是否可行?结论:不可行
public String getImgUrl(String str){
    String data = "";
    try {
        URL u = new URL(str);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String content = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while((content = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(content);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
        String data = "";
        data = getImgUrl(str[0]);
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(s)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(siteHolder.image);
    }
}

class SiteHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView mallName;
    TextView address;
    TextView distance;
    }
}
```

if there anybody who met such scene before, thank you in advance.

Comment: why aint you using glide directly to download and display images? you can use `simpletarget` to download and display images in glide, this might help asychronous updating of list images too.  finally call `notifydatasetchanged` once image is set in postexecute method

Comment: @MohammedAtif I tried your method previously and found error still occur, `simpletarget` is just a imageview callback and will not solve this question.as for`notifydatasetchenged` method, actually i post this question before and tried to use such way also failed. Maybe it's glide cache problem, the first time glide download image data in cache and after rescrolling up, glide put such cache data out and show. if such, can you give me more suggestion?

Comment: its definitely notifydatasetchanged problem.you must call it at the right time. you can add glide listener, and in on resource ready method, call the notifydatasetchanged

Comment: @MohammedAtif I am a little confused, you mean i download data in simpletarget, but you know the actual image url is the `doInBackground` returning value, how can i use such value in simpleadapter. can you make a demo below.I believe your answer maybe is what i want, but i don't know how to amend my code.

Comment: I believe you are downloading image everytime, so using background thread or having custom download manager doesnt make sense, see my answer below, I have completely added the code in your existing method. It shouldnt be a problem for you. And the reason why I am using listener instead of Simple Target is you can listen for both errors and success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While responding at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1508 I discovered the potential root cause of your images not loading: in `getView` you overwrite `siteHolder`, so whichever `ImageTask` finishes, it always updates the last bound row instead of the original row that the task was started for. For more tips on how to improve Glide related code in a double-dispatch case like this, see the issue on GitHub. Quick and dirty fix:

```
public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
    //private SiteHolder siteHolder; // remove this field

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SiteHolder siteHolder = new SiteHolder();
    ...
    ImageTask task = new ImageTask(siteHolder);
    ...
}

static class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private SiteHolder siteHolder; // TODO initialize in constructor
    // rest stays the same, but notice the `static` modifier above!
}
```

Comment: perfect! thank you so much @TWiStErRob, I have read your answer on GH carefully, your analysis are really too incisive, just do it step by step,finally found out the real pain point.

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md#compatibility

> **Round Pictures**: `CircleImageView`/`CircularImageView`/`RoundedImageView` are known to have [issues](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues?q=is%3Aissue+CircleImageView+OR+CircularImageView+OR+RoundedImageView) with `TransitionDrawable` (`.crossFade()` with `.thumbnail()` or `.placeholder()`) and animated GIFs, use a [`BitmapTransformation`](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) (`.circleCrop()` will be available in v4) or `.dontAnimate()` to fix the issue.

In short: the rounding views always rasterize the incoming Drawables into Bitmaps, which won't work if there's an animation inside the Drawable (GIF or crossFade).

On the first load the placeholder is shown while retrieving the image and then crossFaded to the image; later, when you scroll up the image is loaded from memory cache immediately so there's no animation.

Comment: thank you for you answer TWiStErRob, and I have seen the article about compatibility part. added another three external integration-library directly made app crashed , in addition, i still have some curious. First, Round Pictures?you specify some views but i just use imageview and do not use any animation, so dontAnimate also not work.

Comment: Ah, true that. Your placeholder (or whatever that red thing is) is round, that mislead me, but just noticed that the last one is a rectangular image. You **are** using animation, because `crossFade()` is the default. Anyway, I suggest you open a new issue on GH, so we can investigate more together: I have a few suspicions about your ViewHolder pattern and AsyncTask. Please fill in all the details when you open the issue.

Comment: ok, i will do it soon, do you need more code snippets? but i think this is an isolated question, whatever, if you need i will show you more.